# Объекты в Javascript. Какая область видимости?

Tags: javascript, объекты

Есть у нас функция:

```
function createMatrix()
{
    var matrix = document.getElementById('matrix');
    var n = 20 * 20;

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('id', 'div_' + i);
        div.className = 'cell';
        matrix.appendChild(div);
    }
    r = (randomcell(0,399));
    small_div = document.getElementById('div_' + r);
    small_div.className = 'black';
}
```

Вне этой функции я пишу например: `small_div.setAttribute('id', 'div_13');`
Просто чтоб проверить, работает ли. Пишет "small_div is not defined". Почему? Вроде же без var объявление идёт в функции? Я новичок в Javascript. Помогите, пожалуйста, с особенностями при работе с объектами в Javascript. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Объявите small_div как глобальный (вне функции) до начала работы функции. Т.е. как-то так:

```
var small_div = false;
createMatrix();
if (!!small_div)
  alert(small_div.id);
```

Общая инфа: не путайтесь, объявление всегда идет с **var**. Просто использование var внутри функции объявляет ее как локальную.

```
function ga1() { var a = 15; }
function ga2() { a = 13;  }
ga2(); // a is not defined
var a = 11;
alert(a); // 11
ga1(); alert(a); // 11, ибо а - локальная
ga2(); alert(a); // 13
```

Comment: но разве так мы не переменную типа bool объвляем? Если сделать так как вы сказали, то на строку "small_div.setAttribute('id', 'div_13');" пишет "small_div.setAttribute is not a function"

Comment: JS не типизирован) !!small_div дает "not (not (small_div))", т.е. "не является ложной/пустой", а объект не пуст. а вообще js вполне спокойно делает так:
<pre>var a = false; // bool 
a += 5; // int
a = 'lol_'+a; // string
a = {b: a}; // object</pre> Далее: проверьте (`alert(document.getElementById('div_13'))`), что див с id=div_13 существует. Если нет, попробуйте устанавливать ID после `matrix.appendChild(div);`

Comment: Спасибо Sh4dow. Ошибка моя состояла в том, что я не знал, что сначала выполнится всё после точки входа, И ТОЛЬКО ПОСЛЕ ФУНКЦИЯ window.onload. Следственно, матрица и объект small_div создавался в window.onload. А использовать я его хотел уже в не этой функции. В общем обыкновенный ламерский затуп...)